# Add files with CMake

Tags: c++, visual-c++, cmake

I am now building a dynamic library with CMake, and the problem I now meet with is related to adding files for the library. The structure of my project is as follows:

```
----src
     |
  thrid_party---boost_1_50_0----boost
     |       ---   |        ----libs
     |       ---   |        ---- | --- filesystem
     |       ---   |        ---- | ---   |  ------src
```

My CMakeLists.txt file is located in the `src` directory, and the contents of the file are as follows:

```
cmake_minimum_required( VERSION 2.6 )
project (temp)
#build the third party library
include_directories( ${irisimp_SOURCE_DIR}/../third_party/boost_1_50_0)
set (boost_path 
${irisimp_SOURCE_DIR}/../third_party/boost_1_50_0/libs)

set (BOOST_LIST
${boost_path}/filesystem/src/codecvt_error_category.cpp 
${boost_path}/filesystem/src/operations.cpp 
${boost_path}/filesystem/src/path.cpp 
${boost_path}/filesystem/src/path_traits.cpp 
${boost_path}/filesystem/src/portability.cpp 
${boost_path}/filesystem/src/unique_path.cpp 
${boost_path}/filesystem/src/utf8_codecvt_facet.cpp 
${boost_path}/filesystem/src/windows_file_codecvt.cpp 
${boost_path}/filesystem/src/windows_file_codecvt.hpp 
)
add_library ( boost SHARED ${BOOST_LIST})
```

I have no problem with running this script, however, the output Visual Studio 10 project does not contain all the source files in the  `${boost_path}/filesystem/src`folder. In fact only windows_file_codecvt.cpp is kept. Therefore, compiling this project will fail. I was wondering what I should do in order to make sure the Visual Studio 10 project can contain all the source files as instructed in the CMakeLists.txt.Thanks!

Comment: It all looks fine (except the typo "thrid" in your structure diagram). I assume the listed Boost.Filesystem files all actually exist where you specify. You could try outputting the contents of `BOOST_LIST` after you set it: `message("BOOST_LIST: ${BOOST_LIST}")`, or you could get the sources for your `boost` target `get_target_property(BoostSources boost SOURCES)` and output that: `message("BoostSources: ${BoostSources}")` to see if it sheds any light on the problem.

Comment: @Fraser Thanks for the suggestion, and it seems that it only fails in my computer, and if the same script is run in another computer, it is fine. It is related to my computer's setting, I guess.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try putting semicolons in between the paths like so:

```
set (BOOST_LIST
  ${boost_path}/filesystem/src/codecvt_error_category.cpp;
  ${boost_path}/filesystem/src/operations.cpp;
  ${boost_path}/filesystem/src/path.cpp;
  ${boost_path}/filesystem/src/path_traits.cpp; 
  ${boost_path}/filesystem/src/portability.cpp;
  ${boost_path}/filesystem/src/unique_path.cpp;
  ${boost_path}/filesystem/src/utf8_codecvt_facet.cpp; 
  ${boost_path}/filesystem/src/windows_file_codecvt.cpp; 
  ${boost_path}/filesystem/src/windows_file_codecvt.hpp;
)
```

If this doesn't work, try

```
add_library(boost SHARED
  ${boost_path}/filesystem/src/codecvt_error_category.cpp
  ${boost_path}/filesystem/src/operations.cpp 
  ${boost_path}/filesystem/src/path.cpp 
  ${boost_path}/filesystem/src/path_traits.cpp
  ...
  ${boost_path}/filesystem/src/windows_file_codecvt.hpp)
```

This might help debug where the problem lies.

Comment: This would have been a comment, but SO doesn't think me worthy of comments yet.

Comment: Hmm, strange. `BOOST_LIST` should've been list anyways.

Comment: It is strange. Perhaps it might have to do with newlines instead of/without spaces. @arrowdodger from #ogre3d? realazthat here.